# Regex for a plus and minus sign, along with letters?

Tags: python, arrays, regex, parsing, python-re

I'm trying to write a Python function using the `re` library, essentially trying to extract the word that is within the brackets. These words contain letters, and some words contain a plus sign or minus sign (but not all). This is the function I have so far:

```
def processArray(array):
    newArray = []
    for i in array:
        m = re.search(r"\[([A-Za-z0-9\-\+]+)\]", i).groups()[0]
        newArray.append(m)

    return newArray
```

The `array` parameter passed in is `[['Preconditions [+Here]\n'], ['Preconditions [+Is', '+The]\n'], ['Preconditions [-Example]\n']]`. The `newArray` I hope to obtain is `['+Here', '-Is', '+The', '-Example']`. With my current function, this is the error thrown out:

```
  File "file.py", line 71, in <module>
    preconditions = processArray(preconditions)
  File "file.py", line 29, in processArray
    m = re.search(r"\[([A-Za-z0-9\-\+]+)\]", i).groups()[0]
  File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/re.py", line 183, in search
    return _compile(pattern, flags).search(string)
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

Could anyone explain why this error is occurring and what I can do to fix it?

Comment: Do you want to say you want to match these words across items in a list of lists? `['Preconditions [+Is', '+The]\n']` - the `+Is` and `+The` are in different strings in a list.

Comment: In `for i in array`, `i` is a _list_, because `array` is a list of lists. Regular expressions operate only on strings or bytes-like objects

Comment: Did my solution below work for you?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew yes, it worked perfectly. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may iterate over the lists inside the list and join all inner lists and use the following fix:

```py
import re

def processArray(array):
    newArray = []
    for l in array:
        m = re.findall(r"[A-Za-z0-9+-]+(?=[^][]*])", " ".join(l))
        if m:
            newArray.extend(m)
    return newArray

print(processArray([['Preconditions [+Here]\n'], ['Preconditions [+Is', '+The]\n'], ['Preconditions [-Example]\n']]))
# => ['+Here', '+Is', '+The', '-Example']
```

See a [Python demo](https://ideone.com/kKbTRx).

The regex is `[A-Za-z0-9+-]+(?=[^][]*])`, it is a workaround to match one or more alphanumeric or `-`/`+` chars only if followed with 0+ chars other than `[` and `]` up to a `]`. It does not check for the open `[`. If it is necessary, you will have to run two regex operations:

```py
def processArray(array):
    newArray = []
    for l in array:
        m = re.findall(r"\[(.*?)]", " ".join(l))
        for n in m:
            k = re.findall(r'[A-Za-z0-9+-]+', n)
            if k:
                newArray.extend(k)
    return newArray
```

See [this Python demo](https://ideone.com/aDPT5H), where the strings between parentheses are first extracted, and then the necessary matches inside them.